# Differentiate the Function: $f(t)= \sin^2(e^{\sin^2t})$

Tags: calculus

$f(t)= \sin^2(e^{\sin^2t})$

$f'(t)=2\cos(e^{\sin^2t})\cdot e^{\sin^2t}\cdot \cos^2t\cdot (-2\sin t)$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: No.  First of all, the function is not equal to the derivative.  Second, the derivative is incorrect.

Comment: No $\frac{d}{dt}sin^2(y) = 2sin(y)y'$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sin^2\left(e^{\sin^2t}\right)\right]$$
$$=2\sin\left(e^{\sin^2t}\right)\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sin\left(e^{\sin^2t}\right)\right]$$
$$=2\sin\left(e^{\sin^2t}\right)\cos\left(e^{\sin^2t}\right)\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{\sin^2t}\right]$$
$$=\sin\left(2e^{\sin^2t}\right)\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{\sin^2t}\right]$$
$$=\sin\left(2e^{\sin^2t}\right)e^{\sin^2t}\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sin^2t\right]$$
$$=\sin\left(2e^{\sin^2t}\right)e^{\sin^2t}2\sin t\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sin t\right]$$
$$=\sin\left(2e^{\sin^2t}\right)e^{\sin^2t}2\sin t\cos t$$
$$=\sin\left(2e^{\sin^2t}\right)\sin(2t)e^{\sin^2t}$$

Comment: Your work is exceptional.

Comment: @Cetshwayo, thank you. Keep practicing and all of this will become easy to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution needs work. In particular, your use of the equal sign is misleading. Literally, $\sin^2(e^{\sin^2(t)}) \neq 2\cos(e^{\sin^2(t)}) \cdot e^{\sin^2(t)}\cos^2(t) \cdot (-2\sin(t))$.

I think you meant to write: $$f(t) = \sin^2(e^{\sin^2(t)})$$ and $$f'(t)=2\cos(e^{\sin^2(t)}) \cdot e^{\sin^2(t)}\cos^2(t) \cdot (-2\sin(t)).$$

This is something that many students do, and when I see it, I mark it as incorrect. It's important to work out good language skills in mathematics.

In anycase, this is the composition of several functions, and as such we need to use the chain rule:

$$f'(t) = \left( 2\sin(e^{\sin^2 t}) \right) \cdot \cos\left( e^{\sin^2(t)}\right) \cdot e^{\sin^2(t)} \cdot 2 \sin(t) \cdot \cos(t).$$

Let's rewrite our function as a composition of several other functions:

Let $g(t) = t^2$, $h(t) = \sin(t)$, $m(t) = e^t$, $n(t) = t^2$ and $p(t) = \sin(t)$, then $$f(t) = (g\circ h \circ m \circ n \circ p)(t) = g( h( m( n( p(t) ) ) ) )$$

Thus the derivative takes the form:

$$f'(t) = g'(h(m(n(p(t))))) \cdot h'(m(n(p(t))) \cdot m'(n(p(t)) \cdot n'(p(t)) \cdot p'(t).$$

Comment: "It's important to work out good language skills in mathematics." Please elaborate, make me aware.

Comment: When you write down solutions to mathematical problems, you should do so in complete sentences. For instance, in this case we could say:

The derivative of the function, $f(t) = \cdots$, is given by $f'(t) = \cdots$.

Rather than:

$$f(t) = \cos(t) = -\sin(t)$$

If someone were to read this, they would read "The function, $f(t)$, given by $\cos(t)$ is also equal to $-\sin(t)$." If when you read it aloud as a sentence, it doesn't make sense to you, then there is a better way of organizing the statement.

Comment: Just as with an english/grammar class, math should always be written in complete sentences.

Answer (score 1):

$$f^{ \prime  }\left( t \right) =\left( \sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( { e }^{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  } \right)  }  \right) ^{ \prime  }=2\sin { \left( { e }^{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  } \right)  } \cos { \left( { e }^{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  } \right)  } { e }^{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  }2\sin { x } \cos { x } ={ e }^{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  }\sin { 2\left( { e }^{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  } \right)  } \sin { 2x } $$